# Javascript CSS Menu borders / box shadows

Tags: javascript, css, menu, onclick, border

I am trying to create a menu, just for learning purposes and to understand CSS better. Here is my example:

https://jsfiddle.net/3eacLaxz/

The problem is mainly in here:

```
.testul li ul li {
position: fixed;
top: 99px;
list-style: none;
white-space: nowrap;
height: 24px;
line-height: 24px;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#c8bfb0, #f5efe6);
border-bottom: 1px solid #d3c7b6;
z-index: 50;
}
```

My issue is, that once clicked on a menu button, the submenu should display on the far left, and it should just display each submenu link next to each other. As in this example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvBNv.png

I tried using positioning, but I couldn't get it fixed. Whenever I change the position: fixed; in .testul li ul li, the submenu doesn't display at all anymore because I think it opens in the same div, BEHIND the top menu. But if I use "fixed", all LI's get displayed on top of each other on the left, as in the JSfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started on your drop menu position problem...

https://jsfiddle.net/p2dtswy7/1/

Basically what you want to do is to `position:relative` the parent element (the parent li). Then the dropdown (or child) ul you want to give `position:absolute`. You can then start pixel-pushing it around until it plays nicely.

Basically, if you position an element in the DOM with `position:absolute` it will be positioned with reference to the entire document or DOM. However, if you position its parent element `position:relative` the child will be positioned relative to its parent instead.

With regards to your initial problem of the double borders... there would be ways of doing this. I might add dummy list items at the beginning and end of the ul and add the borders/shadows to those. Then you might need to hide their other borders and shadows using :first-child and :last-child. However this solution would generate a lot of unnecessary markup for very little gain... IMHO, I think what you've created already looks bob-on and no client is going to pull you up on such a detail. :)

Comment: Thanks, nice explanation indeed, although since I always want to do everything perfect, I just want to fix those seperators, also becauce I am curious on how to actually accomplish it. Thanks for the explanation though, I will play around with this and see if I can learn anything from it :)

Comment: I like to make everything perfect too... :) but when it comes to professional devving there comes a point where time, effort and bloated code needs to step down in preference for getting a job done on time and on budget... particularly when the only person who will notice the detail is you! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am back to my original problem :D I needed the submenu links to display horizontally, instead of vertically like they are now. Also, when I click on a button, the submenu should be displayed totally on the left. But I can still play around with the positions to see if I can get it fixed :)

Comment: ...same principle, this time it's the parent ul (not li) that has relative positioning, and the child ul that it absolutely positioned. Also the child list items are display:inline-block; - this makes them display in a row.

Comment: Thanks, your answer worked but it didn't work for me, as I am using:

* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

Updated my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3eacLaxz/ as an example.

Comment: Do you mean you're using a CSS wildcard? They can be handy but they can also introduce issues like this - use them with caution. You can always override them using the heavy-handed "!important" hack but your CSS can get messy.

Comment: Just had a look at your fiddle - if you take out "position: fixed" from ".testul li ul li" it seems to work. Is that the solution you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks, but no if it was that easy I would've fixed it :D The problem is that if I remove it, the submenu links aren't displayed totally on the left anymore. That is what I need.

Comment: The way I see it then is there are only two solutions that don't involve a stack of javascript. Either remove your wildcard CSS declaration or start hacking around it with "!important". Either way, the solution you need is to position:relative the parent and position:absolute the child. T'is the only way.